# Knockout components click event from parent

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-components

Lets assume that i have a modal, where there is a FileUpload component in the modal-body made from jquery-file-upload.

This component has a method called "Upload" in the viewmodel, which goes through selected files and uploads them.

Now, I want to upload the files when i press the "upload"-button on the modal. Which is the best and cleanest way to make this happen ?

My code right now is like this (be aware that it's just some quick prototype code):

```
<div data-bind="component:{name:'FileUpload', params:FileUpload}"></div>

<button data-bind="click:test">test</button>
@section Scripts
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/global/fileUpload")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css/fileUploadCSS")
<script type="text/javascript">
    var model = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.FileUpload = {
                url: 'test',
                onFailed: function (e, data) {
                    console.log('failed')
                }
        };
        self.test = function () { console.debug(self.FileUpload) }

    }

    ko.applyBindings(new model(), document.getElementById("main"))
</script>
End Section
```

And the component itself:

```
ko.components.register('FileUpload', {
viewModel: function(params) {
    var self = this;
    self.files = ko.observableArray();
    self.template = params.template;
    self.multiple = params.multiple || false;
    self.progress = ko.observable(0);
    var acceptFileTypes = params.acceptFileTypes || /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf|eps|tiff|cdr|PDF|CDR|JPG|EPS|TIFF|pptx|docx|xlsx|ppt|doc|xls)$/i;
    var maxFileSize = params.maxFileSize || 104857600;
    self.Upload = function() {
        $.each(self.files(), function(index, file) {
            file.submit();
        });
    };

    self.options = {
        type: params.type || "POST",
        dataType: params.dataType || "json",
        formData: params.formData || {},
        url: RTC.SiteUrl() + params.url,
        sequentialUploads: params.sequentialUploads || true,
        dropzone: params.dropzone||$(this),
        autoUpload: params.autoUpload || false,
        forceIframeTransport: true,
        limitMultiFileUploadSize: params.maxFileSize || maxFileSize,
        maxFileSize: params.maxFileSize || maxFileSize,
        done: function (e, data) {
            if (params.onUploaded)
                params.onUploaded(e, data);
            RTC.Progressor.Done();
        },
        fail: function (e, data) {
            if (params.onFailed)
                params.onFailed(e, data);
            RTC.Progressor.Done();
        },
        start: function(e,data) {
            RTC.Progressor.Start();
        },
        progressall: function(e, data) {
            RTC.Progressor.Set(data.loaded / data.total*100);
        },
        add: function (e, data) {
            //if (data.originalFiles[0]['size'] > maxFileSize) {
            //    RTC.addAlert(RTC.translate(220, "[220: File is invalid]"), "alert-danger", RTC.translate(193, "[193: An error occurred]"));
            //} else if (!acceptFileTypes.test(data.originalFiles[0]['name'])) {
            //    RTC.addAlert(RTC.translate(198, "[198: Wrong file format]"), "alert-danger", RTC.translate(193, "[193: An error occurred]"));
            //} else {
                self.progress(0);
                if (!self.multiple)
                    self.files.removeAll();
                self.files.push(data);
           // }
        }
    };
},
template: { element: "fileUploadTemplate" }
});

ko.bindingHandlers.fileUpload = {
update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var options = valueAccessor() || {};
    //initialize
    //.fileInput || $(this),
    $(element).fileupload(options);
    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
        // This will be called when the element is removed by Knockout or
        // if some other part of your code calls ko.removeNode(element)
        $(element)("destroy");
    });

}
};
```

Comment: Not sure from your code if this is the main viewmodel talking to the component, or the component talking to the viewmodel? If the first one it's similar to my query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26931029/communicating-with-knockout-components ? If from the component to the viewmodel you could send a callback function via params that the component calls. e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/Quango/5bxbsLt6/

Comment: It's both. I wanted the button from a modal, to make the component upload its selected file, then use a callback to make the modal close. I got it solved by sending an object to the component, where the component sends a function back, that the modal can use. I feel that its not very pretty, but it works

Comment: Yeah I had the same issues, see so:26931029, For viewmodel-to-component I pass observables to components and then subscribe to these (or use to control component elements indirectly, e.g. dialog visible). For component-to-viewmodel you can pass a callback function as a property via the params. It would be nice to have an 'interface' on a component in some way.

Comment: In some cases, DOM events make for a clean solution, too. I make all my action bindings emit a custom 'I'm done' event that bubbles up, and gave my modal binding a parameter which events to listen to. E.g. `<div data-bind="modal: { closeOn: 'fileupload.done' }"><div data-bind="component:{name:'FileUpload', params:FileUpload}"></div></div>`.